# Monotonicity of semi closure of sets in generalized topological spaces

Tags: generalized-topology

Hi I just want to ask if anybody here can show that if A is a subset of B then the semi closure of A is a subset of the semi closure of B. I know it is true for closure but I want to be sure if it holds for semi closure as well

Comment: Define semi closure and generalized topological spaces, please

Comment: The semi closure of a set is the smallest semi closed set containing the set.

Comment: So, a set is semi-closed if its complement is semi-open?

Comment: A generalized topology is a collection of subsets of X such that the empty set is in the collection and that the union of the elements in the collection is also in the collection

Comment: Yes. A set is semi closed if its complement is semi open

Comment: I think it follows from the result that the union of semi open sets is semi open

Comment: The given collection are then the semi-open sets?

Comment: You have told us what a generalized topology ism but you haven't told us what the "semi-open sets" of a generalized topology are.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this one. What I am not very sure of is if the semi closure of A is a subset of B given that A is a subset of B

Comment: It follows from ***what*** result that the union of semi open sets is semi open? I don't see any "results" here.

Comment: A set is semi open in a generalized topological space if it is a subset of the closure of its interior

Comment: @bof Maybe if you post  that as a question, then  that can be answered. I have a copy of that result.

Comment: How about giving the definitions in order, and putting them in the question, instead of in comments? How are "closure" and "interior" defined in a semitopological space>? How are "open sets" and "closed sets" defined?

Comment: @ΘΣΦGenSan I'd just like to see some ***definitions***. I understand that a "generalized topology" on $X$ is a collection of subsets that is clused under arbitrary union. Fine. What is the definition of an OPEN SET and a CLOSED SET is a generalized topological space? And then what ate the definitions of INTERIOR, CLOSURE, SEMI-OPEN SET, AND SEMI-CLOSED SET?

Comment: @bof It's too long to put them in here. Sorry. But there many articles that cover those terms you mentioned. One good reference is N. Levine, “Semi-open sets and semi-continuity in topological spaces,” The American Mathematical Monthly, vol. 70, pp. 36–41, 1963.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $\underline{A}$ the semi-closure of set $A$. Then (as you mentioned in your comment) $\underline{A}$ is the smallest semi-closed set containing the set $A$.

> We want to show that if $A\subset B$ then $\underline{A}\subset \underline {B}$.

Now, $$A\subset B\subset\underline{B}$$ and this means that $\underline{B}$ is a semi-closed set containing $A$. But $\underline{A}$ is the smallest semi-closed set containing the set $A$ and therefore, $$A\subset\underline{A}\subset \underline{B}.$$
Hope this help.

**Note:** In fact, you can also verify that $A\subset\underline{A}\subset\overline{A}$ where $\overline{A}$ is closure of $A$. This give a relationship between semi-closure and the closure.

Comment: Yeah this helped thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given the definitions in the comments we note that semi-closed sets are closed under arbitrary intersections and $X$ is always semi-closed. This allows us to define the semi-closure $\overline{A}$ of $A \subset X$ as

$$\overline{A} = \bigcap \{C \text{ semi-closed }, A \subseteq C\}$$

Now if $A\subseteq B$, then any semiclosed set $C$ that contains $B$ also contains $A$. So

$$\{C \text{ semi-closed }, B \subseteq C\} \subseteq \{C \text{ semi-closed }, A \subseteq C\}$$

So $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$ as the intersection of a possibly smaller family of subsets is larger.